# Function composition in Scheme

Tags: macros, scheme, function-composition

I'm trying to modify the function below to compose two functions in Scheme.

```
(define (compose F1 F2)
    (eval F1 (interaction-environment))
)
```

rather than

```
(define (compose f g)
  (λ (x) (f (g x))))
```

But I'm not sure about how to use eval.

Comment: What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: Why do you want to use `eval`?

Comment: `eval` doesn't make any sense if you have two two function arguments.

Answer (score 0):

From your suggestion, I guess you want to use Scheme's macros / preprocessing capabilities. `eval` isn't meant for code transformation. Composition `∘` can be defined in Scheme as

```
(define (∘ f g)
        (lambda (x) (f (g x))) )
```

or

```
(define-syntax ∘
   (syntax-rules ()
      ((∘ f g)
       (lambda (x) (f (g x))) )))
```

where the arity of expressions `f` and `g` is 1.

```
(define (plus-10 n) (+ n 10))
(define (minus-3 n) (- n 3))

(display
   (map (∘ plus-10 minus-3)
        (list 1 2 3 4) ))
```

The `map` expression at compile-time becomes

```
(map (lambda (x) (plus-10 (minus-3 x)))
     (list 1 2 3 4) )
```

`equal?`s

```
(list 8 9 10 11)
```